# Overlay 2 PDF documents within a C/C++ application

Tags: c++, pdf

Been trying to figure this problem out for quite a while and haven't had much luck.
So I have this program that outputs a PDF file (1.3 version). The Outputted PDF is basically a plain text PDF so the idea is to have the user open another PDF which has graphics and have the text PDF overlay the other.

However I haven't been able to find any way to do this for C/C++. Is there a API that I could use? Would need to work for both Mac/Windows OS.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of open source and commercial applications that can do this and that have either an SDK or a command-line interface that you could use from C++.

callas pdfToolbox is an example of such an application (but warning, I'm associated with this company). It is also available for Mac, Windows and various Unix / Linux platforms.

My advice would be to more clearly define what exactly you need in terms of tool. Library or command-line? Own code? Free or commercial? Open-source?

To get really useful answers you'll need to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

There are SDK versions of `VeryPDF` and `PDF Editor` programs that allow you to use this software together with other applications like VB, C#, VB.NET, ASP.NET, Delphi, C/C++, ASP, PHP, etc. [here](http://www.verypdf.com/wordpress/201304/how-to-overlay-pdf-to-another-pdf-35885.html)

Comment: I really liked all the posts that were mentioned being that the libraries are all useful. I would have preferred more free options but its good to know some useful SDKs. ANyways what I ended up doing was basically hard coding all the values for the pdf and some basic PDF manipulation. Such as adding "x y l S" and "/F13 12 ... " Thanks for the help everyone.